# how to match a value none or one time in regex using python re.findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I want to match a pattern like java -c 123.java or java 123.java.
See that -c is optional it can come once or none.
So far I am using

```
java\s+-c\s+[\d]+\.java|java\s+[\d]+\.java
```

which is working fine
Please don't check command validity, this is a sample.
I prefer this way than using pipe symbol like

```
java\s+(-c){0,1}\s+[\d]+\.java
```

but when I use re.findall it is returning empty string but working fine with re.search. Since re.findall is compulsory for me, Is grouping like (-c) correct way or can you suggest any changes to the above regex?

Code:

```
seq="java -c 123.java"
pattern="java\s+(-c){0,1}\s+[\d]+\.java"
pattern=re.compile(pattern)
pattern.findall(seq)
```

Output: ['-c']
I want to get java -c 123.java
As @9769953 pointed if `seq="java  123.java"`, output is empty list and if `seq="java  123.java"` #Note the extra spaces, output is [''].
@mozway I have tried what you said when I use

```
java\s+(-c)?\s+[\d]+\.java
```

it's returning ['-c']
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `?` for 0 or 1 match

Comment: Please show the actual code, with `re.findall` etc. You may be calling it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes got it,
Check this :
seq="java -c 123.java"
pattern="java\s+(-c){0,1}\s+[\d]+\.java"
pattern=re.compile(pattern)
pattern.findall(seq)

Comment: @mozway Hi this is what i tried java\s+(-c)?\s+[\d]+\.java, re.findall return ['-c'] ie only the group but re.search is finding <re.Match object; span=(0, 17), match='java  -c 123.java'>
I think it is more than the ? symbol. something related to search and findall

Comment: @9769953 of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to find the whole pattern of `java <possible option flag> option-value` with `re.findall`, while also retaining the possibility to use `re.search` (the latter will only find the first occurrence, if any).

I assume this means the input could be

```
text = "blah blah java -c 123.java blah blah java 123.java"
```

and you want to find the two occurrences.

`re.findall` captures *groups* inside the text string. So you need to group the relevant pattern, which in this case is the full pattern. To avoid capturing also the optional `-c`, you need to make this group non-capturing.

A normal group is surrounded by parentheses; a non-capturing group would start with `(?:` and ends with a normal corresponding closing `)`.

Together with the allowance for single whitespace if `-c` is not present (and not two matches of `\s+\s+`, which would lead to a requirement of at least two whitespace characters)[1], and with the simplification of using a `?` for an optional match, the pattern would be:

```
pattern = r"(java\s+(?:-c\s+)?[\d]+\.java)"
```

This also uses a raw string (by using the `r` prefix), which avoids the interpretation of some blackslashed character as something special, which is often not what one wants in a regular expression.

With the above input text and pattern, the results are now:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(pattern)
>>> regex.findall(text)
['java -c 123.java', 'java 123.java']
>>> regex.search(text)
<re.Match object; span=(10, 26), match='java -c 123.java'>
>>> regex.search(text).group(1)
'java -c 123.java'
```

---

[1] this pattern does not capture `java -c123.java`, which for short (i.e., one-letter) options, is often standard. If you want to also capture that possibility, change the second `\s+` into `\s*`.

Comment: ?: was what I was looking. "Thanks a lot\n"*1000.